# 13.04 gnome session fallback: can´t edit panels

Tags: gnome-classic

I´ve upgraded to 13.04, and installed classic gnome via `gnome-session-fallback`.

I can't edit the panels. Right-clicking does nothing, with or without alt, win, or ctrl.

How can I add/remove widgets and bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bizarrely enough, <kbd>Meta</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>RightClick</kbd> shows the old and trusty panel menu.

Comment: If your system is a VirtualBox machine you have to disable mouse pointer integration for this combination to work.

This applies at least to my system combinations: Host: Ubuntu 12.04, VirtualBox: 4.1.26, Guest additions installed, Guest: Ubuntu 13.04 Raring in Gnome 3 classic mode

Comment: In my VirtualBox machine (without disabling pointer integration), I must press Alt and then Meta keys, before right clicking (Meta and then Alt, doesn't work)

Comment: Remember to disable the annotates via CCSM otherwise the keycombo will not work

Answer (score 0):

rename `~/.gconf/apps/panel` folder and reboot.

When you log back in, you should get the default panels and settings back.

Comment: No such directory in `~/.gconf/apps`. Just an xml, `gnome-terminal` and `nm-applet`

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn search in ubuntu software center for `gnome-panel`, remove and install again

Comment: `gnome-panel` cannot be removed without also removing `gnome-session-fallback`. This would be very destructive. How would it help exactly? By creating the folder so I can rename it? I don't understand where you're taking me

Comment: `meta+alt+right click` works. This is not a good answer. If I didn't know what I was doing, things could've gone wrong. This is not how StackExchange works. Next time, be sure you know the answer before posting, please